# How to get total number of levels in sunburst chart?

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm using a sunburst chart and trying to show the total number of levels in chart.title. I have read about [Levels and Leaves](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Sunburst_Chart#levels_and_leaves) but I haven't found anything that gives me the total number of levels.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RTvg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you'll need to use the tree data traverser: https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.data.Traverser. It'll help you go through the data and count the maximum number of levels. Check this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/2iq3nYxu. Please note that counting starts from 0, which means you'll have to add 1 to the value when showing the result (line 22).